# A NOT macro for negative conditions

Tags: c++

## Motivation

I typically try to avoid using `!` in if-statements, because (to me) it seems easy to overlook. So, I'll usually just spell it out instead, ex: `if (done == false)` instead of `if (!done)`. While that makes the intention more obvious, it doesn't read very fluidly.

## Macro code

For those cases I wrote the following macro:

```
#define NOT(x) ((x) == false)
```

The outer parentheses make it possible to use `NOT(cond)` without additional parentheses in `if` and make it less error prone:

```
if NOT(condition) {
    ...
}
```

## Complete example of macro usage

```
#include <iostream>

#define NOT(x) ((x) == false)

bool successful() {return false;}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if NOT(successful()) {
        std::cout << "Warning! Self-destruction activated...\n";
    }

    const bool this_is_true = true;

    if NOT(this_is_true) {
        std::cout << "True is false.\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## Concerns

While this works, I have some concerns:

1. From a best-practices or clean code perspective, is this frowned upon?
2. How are macros generally viewed, or reported on, in code analysis tools? We are considering employing a system called [CAST-AIP](https://www.castsoftware.com/products/application-intelligence-platform) for code analysis and, while I am strongly in favor of doing so, I am wondering how many volumes of practice violations my reports are going to be.

Comment: Best: Never use macros at all with c++. Don't obfuscate semantics.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there are some very, _very_, ***very*** rare cases where macros _can_ improve code quality and the alternative is more error prone than the macro. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @Zeta Sure, that's why I posted that comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ While, I don't necessarily appreciate the -1, this is exactly the kind of feedback I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what more context one can provide here... this question shouldn't have been closed. It's a simple, one-liner macro, what else one can say about it but providing an example?

Comment: @BlairFonville De nada. Upon more research you'll find exactly that answer easily. Glad to help.

Comment: @BlairFonville may I reword your question so that it's (clearly) on-topic?

Comment: @Zeta By all means. It's funny though - I read the help page on posts before creating this one, and it explicitly says that best-practice questions are on-topic.

Comment: From https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: "Best practices in general: 
It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?""

Comment: Close-reason [discussion on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/what-more-context-can-you-provide-about-a-one-liner-macro)

Comment: @BlairFonville yeah, I actually misread _exactly that part of your question_, since you ask for a *general* view in 2).

Comment: And the fact that the `if` doesn't have an opening `(` is just odd looking

Comment: @Isac Well, it could, of course. Nothing prevents you from wrapping parentheses around it.

Comment: There is a keyword `not` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/not

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like `if (foo == false)` will always be frowned upon. If you find the negation hard to spot you might consider using `not` instead (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) for more info).
E.g. `if (not foo)`

From what I've seen macros are generally discouraged as they tend to obfuscate code and are not typesafe.

Comment: I don't see any sense in waiting to accept this. I can't believe I never knew about these alternative operators. One thing that confuses me is where it reads: "Because in C++ these are built into the language, the C++ version of <iso646.h>, as well as <ciso646>, does not define anything.". Yet it doesn't appear to work without including one.

Comment: @BlairFonville MSVC? AFAIK they don't (or at least didn't) implement that correctly. You can probably use [`/FI` (force include)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file) to make it work without it.

Comment: @Justin You guessed it, VS2017. When I followed the not operator, I found that it resolves to iso646.h : #define not !. Where iso646.h, is included in their ciso646 header. I'll look into /FI, but from it's name, it sounds like it just going to save me the one "#include <ciso646>" line, by doing it for me.

Comment: @BlairFonville Yes, that's what it would do. The good thing about that is that it would improve the quality of the code, as your build system would be taking care of the non-standard stuff.

Comment: @BlairFonville Actually, it [looks like `/permissive-` fixes the issue](https://godbolt.org/g/TH12G8)

Comment: @Justin Though, the only bad thing about making it work this way, is that the operator is not color-formatted in the editor. A battle for another day, I think.

Comment: +1, never knew C++ had a standard `not` operator like this!

Comment: For some reason habits that hinder readability are traditional and very tenacious in the C/C++ world. The keywords `not`, `and` and `or` (as well as several others) as alternative representations of `!`, `&&` and `||` exist for ages, but few seem to know about them, let alone use them; personally I always use them (except then `&&` means "rvalue reference"). I also always avoid implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` (writing `if (i!=0)` if that is what I mean), though that does not prevent me from occasionally getting bitten by an unintended implicit conversion.

Comment: @BlairFonville Do you mean it's not part of the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio? Most modern editors will either highlight it by default or allow you to include new words to be highlighted. Try an editor like vim/emacs/textadept/sublimetext all of those should support it.

Answer (score -4):

why not just

```
#define NOT !
```

It would be simpler to use.

Comment: or just #include<iso646.h>, which does precisely that - per the discussion in comments of yuri’s answer.